# Handling user-settings with doctrine

Tags: database-design, symfony, doctrine-orm, schema

I'm building an application with Symfony2 and using Doctrine as my ORM.

My users are going to need to store a fairly large number of configurations/settings that are specific to them (think 'would you like to receive emails from us?' as a typical example of a setting to be stored).

What is the best way for me to structure this?

Should I add properties to my user entity for each setting?

```
protected $receiveEmails;
```

Or should I create a 'userSetting' entity, with a manyToMany relationship with my user object and have the userSetting entity have two other properties:

```
protected $setting;
protected $value;
```

?

My main reason for asking is performance. I would prefer having a property on the user object so certain settings can be boolean in type, others string etc, but don't want to have my site fetch these values out of the database everytime I get the current user entity (pretty much every page since my authentication backs off the user entity in my db).

What's the answer? Do I need to go back and re-write any instances of using:

```
....getRepository('AcmeMainBundle:User')->find($id)
```

With custom repository functions that only select the elements I need for that situation?

Or am I over-optimizing?

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways.

1) Make a separate entity with `ManyToMany` relationship as you said.

2) Make a separate entity with `OneToOne` relationship where every property of the entity is a setting name.

I would choice the second option because of a perfomance. One row with many columns is better than many one-column rows. And also it is easier to handle and implement.

Comment: The second option makes sense. Am I correct in assuming that going this route, none of my 'settings' entities would be loaded unless I explicitly call the getMySetting getter method on my user object?

Comment: @anonymous, if you make your oneToOne eager loading settings will always be loaded.